# While Loop in Python - Array Manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am working on the following Python codes.

I am hoping to accomplish the following:

1. Create a `total_fold_array` which will hold 5 items (folds)
2. For each fold, create an array of data from a larger dataset based off of the logic (which I know is correct) inside of my `for...zip` loop

To help you understand:
The classses and class_weights returns:
`[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]` and `[0.14285714 0.14285714 0.14285714 0.14285714 0.14285714 0.14285714
 0.14285714]`

The `while count !=6` is not working properly. In short, what I am trying to accomplish is to populate the `total_fold_array` with 5 individual folds, which each contain a number of rows from a dataset.

An example of the `current_fold_array` might be `[A,B,C,D]`, so then ultimately, I have a `total_fold_array` which has 5 of those individual folds, which would look like `[[A,B,C,D,],[A,B,B,C],[A,A,A,A],[B,C,D,D],[B,B,B,C]]`

However, this loop does not do that. Instead, it creates `total_fold_array` with the length of whatever the length of `classes` is (in this case 7), instead of having 5 folds within.

My code is below:

I am currently getting a `total_fold_array` containing 7 items, when instead, it should contain 5. Each item within can have as many items as needed, but the `total_fold_array` should be 5 items long. I believe there is a logic bug in my code, and I am looking for some help. If I were to use a dataset with 5 classes, this works appropriately.

Please let me know if I need to make this clearer.

Comment: Is `count = count + 1` indented properly? The indentation for the last two lines look suspicious also.

Comment: Not sure @wwii. I tried moving them up 1 layer and instead get a `total_fold_array` size of 1, so I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before `for a_class,a_class_weight in zip(classes, class_weights):`, you're initializing total_fold_array to `[]`.

That loop executes for **exactly as many times as there are elements in `classes`**.

Each iteration of that loop appends a `curr_fold_array` to `total_fold_array`.

That is why, at the end of that loop, you have as many elements in `total_fold_array`, as there are in `classes`.

You've enclosed all of this in `while count != 6:`. That seems totally unnecessary -- I think that `while` loop will execute exactly once. You are returning from that function before the second iteration of that `while` loop can happen. My guess is that you introduced that `while` loop hoping that it would somehow limit the number of elements in `total_fold_array` to `5`. But that's not going to happen, because, inside that `while` loop, the `for` loop grows `total_fold_array` to have 7 elements, and this happens in the very first iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: thank you, this was extremely helpful. Your intuition regarding the while loop is correct. If I understand your answer appropriately, I need to move the instantiation of the total array to outside the while loop which ensures I properly create 5 folds, right?

Comment: That really depends upon some details of what you're intending to do, which I don't have. If I were to make a wild guess, try reducing the indent of the last four lines by one indentation level (that would bring the return statement out of the `while` loop, and the append statement out of the `for` loop. Retain the rest of the code as it currently stands, including the `while` loop. Perhaps that would give you the result you are looking for - but I'm only second-guessing your program's objectives.

Comment: How can I improve my question to better explain my intentions? In short, I just need to create an array with 5 elements, where each element itself is an array that is a result of the logic in the class loop.

Comment: The suggestion I've mentioned above will definitely ensure that `total_fold_array` has 5 elements. But what I'm not sure about is whether the **content within** will be correct or not (consistent with your expectations of what that content should be). So far, you've only stated that `total_field_array` should have 5 elemements, but you've not mentioned any details of what the content  of those 5 elements should be.

Comment: The classes and class weights that are described in the post vary in size, but essentially, they are uses to loop through a large dataset and append a certain number of elements to a "fold", or one of those 5 elements.

Comment: If the `for` loop is intended to construct a fold, the actual *appending* of the fold, to `total_fold_array`, must happen **just outside** the `for` loop, and inside the `while` loop. Currently, in the code that you've posted, the appending happens **inside** the `for` loop. My suggestion above (to reduce indentation of the last four lines), was based on that observation. Try it out.

Comment: Though this suggestion will ensure 5 folds, I'm afraid the content of all the 5 folds is going to be the same (no differences among the folds). That is because, your `for` loop, which constructs each fold, does **exactly the same thing** for each iteration of the enclosing `while` loop. Eg, it doesn't in any way make use of any variables that change with the iterations of the `while` loop (such as the variable `count`)

Comment: You got it. I will try these suggestions immediately. I'm sorry for a delay in responding.

Comment: unfortunately, the suggestion (when implemented) just results in `total_fold_array` having one item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189784/discussion-between-jerry-m-and-fountainhead).